# .so file, No Such File or directory, C++

Tags: c++, linux, linker, dependencies, .so

I am building a project from an exmaple project. I have created a "HelloWorld" project just to test .h includes and .so libraries. I had some issues with .h files as I am a complete beginner at C++ and I am taking elements of a sample project to build my own. I have no issues running the windows example. I have had this running and modified it. I am currently using a BeagleBone AI board running Debian 9 as a remote server for linux debugging. I have added the Include directory to the .h files in Visual Studio and these are being recognised, I have added the .so file to the linker settings in Visual studio but I am getting no such file or directory error when building it. I have checked the project folder on the BeagleBone to make sure the file exists and it does.

I cannot figure out why the program is not seeing it when it is there. I ahve a few questions to try and get some answers on this. Please bare in mind I am new to C++ and learning as I go.

1. Does Linux need anything installed to use .so files or should shared object files just work on linux without any other dependencies?

Below is the project and settings, if anyone has any suggestions it would be appreciated. I have used images as there is no real code in this yet, just trying to get the Shared Object file to be seen before I go any further.

File System
[image]

Inlcude Files Which the program is seeing
[image]

Shared Object file which is not being found
[image]

Visual Studio Settings
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Linux File System From Building Project
[image]
[image]
[image]

File Not Recignized after ,oving picozense_api to Library Dependencies:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the shared library that is not being found by the linker
is `libpicozense_api.so`.

Remove `libpicozense_api.so` from the **Linker** -> **Input** -> **Additional Dependencies**
settings and instead, in the **Linker** -> **Input** -> **Library Dependencies** settings
enter `picozense_api`. Not `libpicozense_api.so`.

These settings generate library options for the GCC linkage command. A library option has the form `-lname`. It directs the linker to search, first in the
specified linker search directories (`-Ldir`) and then in the linker's
default search directories, for either of the files `libname.so` (a shared library)
or `libname.a` (a static library), and to prefer `libname.so` if both files
are found in the same search directory. The IDE expects you to know that
**Linker** -> **Input** -> **Library Dependencies** is where to specify
a semi-colon seperated list of the `name`s that should be passed as `-lname`
options in the linkage command.<sup>1</sup>

An unqualified filename, like `libpicozense_api.so`, specified in
**Linker** -> **Input** -> **Additional Dependencies** will simply add
exactly that filename to the linkage command and then it will be found
only if there is a file of that name in the directory where the command
is executed, which there isn't.

---

[1] Operating a GCC toolchain through the medium of an IDE is fraught with
gotchas like this if you don't have a grounding in how the toolchain itself works.
If you lack such a grounding, you can get it from [An Introduction to GCC](https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/an_introduction_to_gcc/)

Comment: Hi Mike, Thanks for the information, it has cured that issue but have come acroos another one. I am getting a file not recognixed: File Format not recognized when I move libpicozense_api to the Library Dependencies. I know I am close to getting this running and hopefully can get it there. The Comment won't let me add in a picture to show, I will add it to the end of the original post so you can see what is hapeening. Thanks